# Silver Nitrate Electrolysis

Tags: experimental-chemistry, redox, electrolysis, silver

i have a solution of silver nitrate at 1M. the aim of my experiment is to determine in 40 mins, how much Ag will be deposited. Should i use copper or graphite electrodes.

Comment: How much will deposit? Nothing. You forgot to turn on the current.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you do it with graphite electrodes.

Because:

- Its  more inert than copper
- If copper is used, it readily reacts and more copper will be deposited at the cathode compared to silver
- the yield of silver will be greatly reduced

Comment: Also, Ag *might* migrate into the copper electrode... Hg certainly does.

Comment: Also, If i have a solution of AgNO3 (is diluted with water), what will oxidise and what will reduce. What are the half reactions?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik